# Unwrapping Optional JSON Element Crashes App

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, option-type

I have a problem unwrapping an optional element in my JSON nested array. The elements in question are labeled as "solo_competitive_rank" and "score". For reference, when a tableview cell in one controller is clicked, these elements should be displayed in a new view controller. While this works sometimes, when a cell that is selected does not have these values, the app crashes. Could someone please assist me in properly unwrapping these elements?

**JSON Struct**

```
struct PlayerStatsParent:Decodable{
let rankings: [PlayerStats]
}


struct PlayerStats:Decodable {
let personaname: String?
let score: Double?
let solo_competitive_rank: Int?
let avatar: String?   
}
```

**Display View**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    rankLabel.text = "\((playerRank?.solo_competitive_rank)!)"
    scoreLabel.text = "\((playerRank?.score)!)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend wrapping each label in an if statement. Like so:

```
if let soloRank = playerRank?.solo_competitive_rank as? Int {
   rankLabel.text = String(soloRank)
}

if let score = playerRank?.score as? Double {
   scoreLabel.text = String(score)
}
```

Comment: should probably convert it to text, since it's an Int. :)

Comment: How do I go about converting it to text?

Comment: @ChrisSwinson - I updated the answer with the String(score). That will convert it to a string before setting it as the label.